# PHP Mail results in error: "header missing"

Tags: php, forms, email

I've been using a php mail form for some time now and now it's not working on a new website.

The following error results:

> PHP Warning:  mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in E:\home\ -mypagefoldername- \Web\form.php on line 16

This is the php code in the form.php file:

```
<?
$mensagem = "Nome: ".$_POST['nome']." \n";
//email que o usuário preencheu
$mensagem .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']." \n";
$mensagem .= "Assunto: ".$_POST['assunto']." \n";
$mensagem .= "Telefone: ".$_POST['fone']." \n";
$mensagem .= "Endereço: ". $_POST['mensagem'];
$headers = "";
//email do seu domínio hospedado
$emailsender = "email@mydomain.com";
//email de quem vai receber
$emaildestinatario = "email@mydomain.com";
$assunto = "Mensagem do Parceiro Pipa";

// Envio dos dados do Formulário para seu e-mail:
if(!mail($emaildestinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers ,"-r".$emailsender))

{ 
// Se for Postfix - hospedagem linux
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailsender . $quebra_linha; 
}
echo '
<script type="text/JavaScript">
alert("Email sent! Thank you!");
location.href="index.html"
</script>
';

?>
```

Sorry about the portuguese.

The form page is a simple html page with the following form code:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">

                    <label>Nome</label>
                    <input name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo.">

                    <label>Telefone</label>
                    <input name="fone" placeholder="Número de telefone com DDD.">                    

                    <label>Assunto</label>
                    <input name="assunto" placeholder="Qual o motivo do seu contato?">                    

                    <label>Mensagem</label>
                    <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem."></textarea>



                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email para contato.">

                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Could somebody please help me? =/

Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Please change the following settings in php.ini file

to enable email you should uncomment the following line or remove the semicolon at the begining of the line

```
;sendmail_from =
```

and change this setting to this for example (if localhost)

```
sendmail_from = localhost@localhost
```

if you are on a production server you have to change the default address according to your domain, so administrator@domain.com

Comment: How do I get to my php.ini file? Should I contact my hosting provider about it or should I go and try to do it myself? Thanks for your help!

Comment: user2092317 if you are still around I have sendmail_from set BUT if is not being received by sendmail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you're probably missing the `From:` declaration in your `$headers` variable!

```
<?php
   $From = "YourEmailAddress@example.com";
   $headers .= "From: Your Name <". $From .">\n";
?>
```

To the near the top of your `$headers` string. Although for future reference, you might want to take a look at PHPMailer Class, a very good & secure class that handles the PHP `mail` efficiently.

[**PHPMailer Github**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Tried using it exactly like this, but it still results in the same error.

Comment: Did you try putting it at the top? because otherwise you're overwriting `$headers` ;o Or change `=` to `.=`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a ***From*** header, which is causing that issue, exactly as stated in the documentation below.

> Note:
>
> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be
>   set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in
>   php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning:
>   mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header
>   missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

In your case, you should use;

```
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Well, I tried doing that. I noticed there was a `$headers =""` empty right before the  `$emailsender` part, and I edited that like your example. Was that it? It still comes back with the same error, I'm afraid. =/

Comment: I think you have something wrong with the "if(!mail())" line, correct usage would be "mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);"